# fopen file with "special" characters in filename

Tags: c++, file, utf-8, character-encoding

With this code I'm able to process any file, except for those that contain "special" characters such as accented letters (à, è, ì, ò, ù ...) and the letters of oriental alphabets

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, ".65001");
FILE* F=fopen("Example.ogg", "rb");
```

As I wrote above, the problem occurs when instead of "Example.ogg" I insert a file, for example, called "Exàmple.ogg" or "究 極 の 聖 戦 バ ト .ogg". With such examples, it is as if he cannot open the file. I searched the web for a long time for a solution, but found nothing.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using wide characters? Like: `FILE* F=wfopen(L"Exàmple.ogg", L"rb");` (could be `_wfopen` on Windows/MSVC).

Comment: I'm working wih MinGW: 
`FILE* F=fopen(L"Exàmple.ogg", L"rb")` returns this error message:
`error: no matching function for call to 'fopen'
stdio.h:600:17: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const wchar_t [3]' to 'const char *__restrict' for 2nd argumen`

Comment: You need to change `fopen` to `wfopen` to take the `wchar_t` arguments.

Comment: Please, try [google "std::fopen wide char"](https://www.google.com/search?q=std%3A%3Afopen+wide+characters) to find more about this.